# Changing the source of an svg element with css

Tags: css, svg

There are a couple of handy solutions to make image content dynamic using css. I think mainly of constructs like this:

```
div {
    background-image: url(my-image.png);
}
```

and

```
div:before {
   content: url(my-image.png)
}
```

Now, what if my source is an svg document and I want to use the viewBox attribute. Is there any way I can change the content of an svg element using css? Ideally I would like something like:

```
svg {
    content: url(my-svg-doc.svg);
}
```

But that's not working.

The reason is that I have 4 different .svg files and I want to show each of them depending on the parent elements css-class. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *use the viewBox attribute*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying with `content`.

It would work with `background-image`.

[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/wgj41hLz/)